# jQGrid AJAX call form edit dialog box

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

is it possible to make an AJAX call while the user is still entering information within the edit dialog box ? I think I need to make the AJAX call for inside the

```
    afterShowForm
```

event. What i want to do is make some changes to the back end database before the user finishes entering all the data in the edit dialog box. I would also like the grid to reload once the AJAX call is completed. Is this possible ? I am using JSON data, will this cause any problems with AJAX call ?

please help

Thanks